# How to create bibliography in LyX

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I use Lyx (Layout report) for my thesis and i need your help on adding Bibliography..

I added bibliography, but how can i add reference at each nunber in my text. For example i want when clicking on the number into the text (e.x. [1] ) to referee to the same nymber in bibliography..

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cite an item from your bibliography in the text, choose Insert --> Citation, or click the Add citation button on the toolbar: [image]

In the window that pops up you'll get a list of items in the bibliography, double click the one(s) you want to cite, and press OK.

Comment: Thank you. That did work !
But i have another issue now : The colour of citation is green and i dont like it.. can i change it to blue ?

Comment: That is a rather different question, but yes: Document --> Settings --> PDF Properties. In the Hyperlinks tab, I guess the box for Color links is checked? In the *Additional options*  field, add `citecolor=blue`.