# Lyx : change cross reference color

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color, lyx

When i make a refference to a figure , the text appears black. How can i change cross reference's default black color to blye or cyan ?

I had the same issue with citations but i figured it out with this (see in comments) :  [How to create bibliography in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75956/how-to-create-bibliography-in-lyx)

Is it possible to do something like that for refferences ?

Comment: Which color? The color displayed inside Lyx or the color of the link in the pdf produced?

Comment: the color of the link in the pdf produced !
For example : The color of text "see figure 1" witch is linkes with the figure 1

Comment: So, you need to check the manual of `hyperref`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98528/19156 for example

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I did it by adding the command \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}  before the refferrence :)

Comment: And to do it for the whole document I imagine you can Document > Settings > PDF Properties > Additional options and put "linkcolor=blue" ?

Comment: i tried that but nothing happened :-(

Comment: You better write this command in your preamble, so that it will apply to the whole document

Comment: To summarize and extend: Under "Document > Settings > PDF Properties" (using hyperref) add `linkcolor=blue` to "Additional Options" and check the box "Color links" in the tab "Hyperlinks". Now working?